# Wait for method to Finish, and weird interaction with System.println

Tags: java, wait

I am trying to write a genetic program to play through a game, but I am running into a bit of a snag.  When I call this code:

```
public double playMap (GameBoard gb, Player p) {
    gb.playerController = p;
    Game g = new Game(gb);
    int initHP = 0;
    for (Unit u : gb.enemy.units) {
        initHP += u.maxHP;
    }

    g.playGame(false);

    int finalHP = 0;
    for (Unit u : gb.enemy.units) {
        finalHP += u.currHP;
    }
    System.out.println("        " + initHP);
    System.out.println("        " + finalHP);
    System.out.println("        " + (finalHP - initHP));
    if (initHP == finalHP) {
        return -10;
    }
    return initHP - finalHP;
}
```

the g.playGame() line does not have time to finish, and I am getting incorrect results from the function.  I can wait out unit the game is over with a

```
while (!g.isDone) {
    System.out.println(g.isDone);
}
```

but not with the same while loop without a print statement.  I know there has to be a more elegant solution, and I cant seem to implement the methods I have seen.  Also if anyone knows why I need the print statement in the while loop to get it to wait that would be great too.

Thanks in advance.

ADDED playGame:

```
public void playGame(boolean visual) {
    Global.visual = visual;
    if (Global.visual) {
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        application.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        application.add(this);           


        application.setSize(500, 400);         // window is 500 pixels wide, 400 high
        application.setVisible(true); 
    }

    PlayerInput pi = new PlayerInput();
    this.addKeyListener(pi);

    final Timer timer = new Timer(10/60, null);
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pi.addPressed();
            if (update(pi)) {
//                  application.setVisible(false);
//                  application.dispose();
                System.out.println(gb.toString());
                isDone = true;
                timer.stop();

            }
            pi.reset();
        }
    };
    timer.addActionListener(listener);
    timer.start();


    while (!isDone) {
        System.out.println(isDone);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how the Game class and its method playGame() are implemented?

Comment: I added the method and as the class is rather large I will just link the git repo. [https://github.com/RyTaus/SURP/blob/master/DoH/Game.java](https://github.com/RyTaus/SURP/blob/master/DoH/Game.java)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is a really bad way of doing this.  This approach is called "busy waiting" and it is very inefficient.

The problem is most likely that reads and writes to `g.isDone` are not properly synchronized.  As a consequence, there are no guarantees that the "waiting" thread will *ever* see the update to `g.isDone` that sets it to true.

There are various ways to ensure that the update is seen.  The simplest one is to declare `isDone` as `volatile`.  Another one is to do the reads and writes within a primitive lock.

The reason that the `println()` call "fixes" things is that println is doing some synchronization behind the scenes, and this is leading to serendipitous cache flushing (or something) that makes your update visible.  (In other words: you got lucky, but *exactly how* you got lucky is hard to tie down.)

---

A better solution is to use another mechanism for coordinating the two threads.

- You could use `Thread.join()` so that one thread waits for the other one to terminate (completely!).
- You could use a `Latch` or `Semaphore` or similar to implement the waiting.
- You could use an `Executor` that delivers a `Future` and then call `Future.get()` to wait for that to deliver its result.
- You could even use `Object.wait` and `Object.notify` ... though that is low-level and easy to get wrong.

Without seeing the full context, it is hard to judge which approach would be most appropriate.  But they would all be better than busy-waiting.

---

Another answer says this:

> If you remove the System.out.println() call from your loop, I believe that the compiler simply doesn't include the loop in the Java bytecode, believing it to be superfluous.

As I explained above, the real problem is inadequate synchronization.  To be technical, there needs to be a *happens-before* relationship between the write of `isDone` in one thread and the read of `isDone` in the other one.  Various things will give that ... but without that, the compiler is entitled to assume that:

1. the writing thread does not need to flush the write to memory
2. the reading thread does not need to check that the memory has changed.

For example, without the *happens-before*, the compiler would be permitted to optimize

```
while (!g.isDone) {
     // do nothing
}
```

to

```
if (!g.isDone) {
     // do nothing
}
```

We don't know if this actually happens, or whether the actual cause of "non-visibility" of the update to `isDone` is something else.  (Indeed, it could be JVM version / platform specific.  To be sure, you would need to get the JIT compiler to dump the native code for the methods, and analyze the code very carefully.)

Comment: Thank you so much.  I knew it was inefficient, but it was the only way I could figure out a bandaid fix.  looks like I have some reading to do on threads and synchronization.

Comment: It looks like you will.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are running your game in a separate thread. Assuming that thread is called `foo`, calling `foo.join()` will block the calling thread until `foo` finishes executing. You can simply replace your entire loop with `foo.join()`.
If you remove the `System.out.println()` call from your loop, I believe that the compiler simply doesn't include the loop in the Java bytecode, believing it to be superfluous.

Comment: How would I find the name of the thread created for the game? Also, when I do something like increment a variable and print it after the loop, (as to not make it superfluous) java still doesn't wait.

Comment: *"If you remove the System.out.println() call from your loop, I believe that the compiler simply doesn't include the loop in the Java bytecode, believing it to be superfluous."* - It won't do that.  The actual problem is likely to be that `g.isDone` reads and writes are not properly synchronized.

Comment: How would I properly synchronize the reads and writes? @StephenC ?

Comment: See my answer.  There is more to it than that.